# Rails copy identical app on postgres - data not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

We have an existing Rails 3 app that has been copied and loaded on a separate server. We've setup the posgres DB for this server; and also configured the database.yaml, pg gems, etc to setup for the port.

However, only the database schema can be migrate...though all the data files has the correct content.

I've tried variations of the db migrate, dump, resets, load, etc.  But I'm not success getting the actual data in the database.  Again, the server migration is for identical hardware/software config.  So, its Rails3.1/Postgres9/Ruby 1.92

I don't get any errors, the data doesn't populate.  The ultimate goal is to have an identical app on the 2 servers.

Any ideas?  I've already spent 4 days fighting.  Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*...the actual data in the database*"

If you have an existing database with transactional data - then I think you want to use postgres tools to move the database? maybe I am not understanding the question correctly?

1. on the source machine

   `pg_dump DATABASE_NAME > ~/DATABASE_NAME_dump.sql`
2. copy the dump file to the target machine
3. on the target machine

   `bundle exec rake db:create`

   `psql DATABASE_NAME < ~/DATABASE_NAME_dump.sql`

lots of good information here - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/backup.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the taps gem?

It enables you to transfer schema and data from one instance to another.